# Best way to softly close application from inno setup during upgrade

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

I have used this code for years to close my running apps during upgrade from INNO SETUP, but now its not working well with a some versions of app.
Any ideas, what is a better way to close running process (delphi app)? 
I need to make it work well during silent setup so no dialogs...

```
  h := FindWindowByWindowName('Myapp');
  v1 := $0016; //WM_ENDSESSION
  v2 := $80000000;// ENDSESSION_LOGOFF
  if h<>0 then PostMessage (h,v1,1,v2);
```

Comment: *Why* do you use magic numbers instead of their symbolic names (that you hide in comments)???

Comment: Well, what has changed? In any case, WM_ENDSESSION seems wrong to me. Your are lying to the app. Only the system should send that message. Pick a message in the WM_APP range, or use RegisterWindowMessage, and send that. Get your app to respond by shutting down. Or ask the user to do it.

Comment: Well, I am shutting down the various old version(s) that I cannot change anymore, so I need to send a message to them or use some other technique.   Btw these constants do not seem to work in Inno setup..

Comment: Can you modify your application to register a custom message ?

Comment: @Uli, probably because this code is in Inno Setup's script interpreter, not in Delphi. Inno doesn't export *all* of Delphi's constants or functions.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Thanks, @Rob!

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some debugging. Run your program in the debugger and check whether your window receives the message. Check what it does in response. You've already released this program, so it's too late to fix, but you can still figure out what's wrong, and you might discover what changes you can make to the installer to compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Vista and later, you should use the Windows Restart Manager (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524.aspx)

InnoSetup supports it directly, check the [CloseApplications] directive. When run in quiet mode, it will close applications without asking the user.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work better:

```
[Code]
const
  WM_CLOSE = $0010;

...
  if h <> 0 then
    PostMessage(h, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
...
```

Comment: Yes, that's one common method that is reasonable. Personally I think it's best to ask the user to do it.

Comment: I needed a solution for Silent Setup so no way to ask user.. :(